# how to get an attribute getter as a Func<object,object>?

Tags: c#, optimization, lambda

**Intro**
I am working on some code that relies heavily on reflection. Some parts that are at the core are used repeatedly. Optimizing this in even the slightest way will give me a lot(to various degrees) of performance benefits.

**Context**
The core consists of getting data out of an object. Currently I use reflection to get a PropertyInfo object, and then use the following code to construct a Func<object,object>:

```
    public static Func<object, object> BuildUntypedGetter(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
    var targetType = propertyInfo.DeclaringType;
    var methodInfo = propertyInfo.GetGetMethod();
    var exTarget = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "t");
    var exBody0 = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Convert(exTarget, targetType);
    var exBody = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(exBody0, methodInfo);
    var exBody2 = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Convert(exBody, typeof(object));

    var lambda = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object>>(exBody2, exTarget);

    var action = lambda.Compile();
    return action;
    }
```

This resulting Func<object,object> is what I then cache and use. The actual typing and security for not calling it on other objects types but the original is something I do not have to worry about as this is taken care of.

In the above code, the lambda that is created looks like the following:

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[System.Object,System.Object]>(System.Object $t) {
    (System.Object).Call ((MyObjectType)$t).get_Id()
}
```

where Id is the attribute that this was generated on.

As you can see, this is merely a redirection. All it does is call the getter.

**Question**
Is there a way to just return the getter (get_Id) as a `Func<object,object>` without the extra cast and call? OR are there maybe other more efficient ways to call an object.attribute getter with an object type as instance type?

Comment: Is the property returning a reference type, or a value type? Or both?

Comment: Both value and reference types will need to be supported. However I guess we can get this information from the meta data in advance, and then possible generate differentiated code if required (eg, if (valuetype) { create value lambda } else { create reference lambda }.

Comment: Hmm, there's the Delegate.CreateDelegate method. Not sure if it allows casting objects.

Comment: I’m general, no, this is not possible.  It would require the input type `T` to be covariant, which is not legal.  Furthermore, the output type `TReturn` is only covariant for reference types; a `Func<,object>` is not assignable from a `Func<,int>` or other primitive special specialization.

Comment: @Wazner I have checked that method. However as I understand (possibly wrongly), delegates are bound to a specific **instance** for non-static methods. I need to be able to call the getter on multiple objects without creating a new delegate

Comment: @Floris I believe that it will bind the target to the first parameter for instance methods.  Nevertheless, you can't bind your accessor to a `Func<object, object>` using this method: the argument type is not compatible (`MyObjectType` is not assignable from `object`), and for primitive values, the return types is not compatible.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to just return the getter (get_Id) as a
>   Func without the extra cast and call?

C# will not let you call getter without the cast (of course with the exception of `dynamic` type, but that's another story), because that would violate type safety, that C# guarantees.

But you can emit IL code, that does not contain such cast and calls getter directly. Of course, when you outsmart compiler like this, it is then your responsibility to call this method only on objects of correct type, otherwise your application is likely to crash.

Following code shows how to emit such IL code. My measurements indicates, that in *Release* mode, emitted delegate is approx. 3x faster than your compiled lambda (in *Debug* mode, it seems to be actually a bit slower).

```
public static Func<object, object> EmitUntypedGetter(PropertyInfo pi)
{
    DynamicMethod method = new DynamicMethod(
        "PropertyGetter",
        typeof(Object),
        new[] { typeof(Object) },
        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().ManifestModule);

    ILGenerator il = method.GetILGenerator(100);

    // Load object onto the stack.
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);

    // Call property getter
    il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, pi.GetGetMethod(), null);

    // If property returns value-type, value must be boxed
    if(pi.PropertyType.IsValueType)
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Box, pi.PropertyType);

    // Exit method
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    return (Func<Object, Object>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<Object, Object>));
}
```

---

## EDIT:

On my computer, performance of emitted code is consistently much faster that lambda version.

Tested on Windows 10 Home, CPU Intel Core2 Q9400, compiled with Visual Studio 2017 CE v. 15.4.0, Console App targeting .NET Framework 4.7, Release mode (*Optimize code* option in project properties enabled), **executed outside of Visual Studio** (with VS attached, some optimizations are disabled)

My results:

```
Compiled lambda (value type)     : 40827 ms
Compiled lambda (reference type) : 37558 ms
Emit (value type)                : 16963 ms
Emit (reference type)            : 11903 ms
```

Program used for testing:

```
public struct MyClass
{
    public int I => 42;
    public string S => "foo";
}

public static void Main()
{
    var valueTypeProperty = typeof(MyClass).GetProperty("I");
    var referenceTypeProperty = typeof(MyClass).GetProperty("S");

    var lambdaValueTypeGetterDelegate = BuildUntypedGetter(valueTypeProperty);
    var lambdaReferenceTypeGetterDelegate = BuildUntypedGetter(referenceTypeProperty);
    var emitValueTypeGetterDelegate = EmitUntypedGetter(valueTypeProperty);
    var emitReferenceTypeGetterDelegate = EmitUntypedGetter(referenceTypeProperty);

    //warm-up - ensures that delegates are properly jitted
    lambdaValueTypeGetterDelegate(new MyClass());
    lambdaReferenceTypeGetterDelegate(new MyClass());
    emitValueTypeGetterDelegate(new MyClass());
    emitReferenceTypeGetterDelegate(new MyClass());

    TestDelegate("Compiled lambda (value type)     ", lambdaValueTypeGetterDelegate);
    TestDelegate("Compiled lambda (reference type) ", lambdaReferenceTypeGetterDelegate);
    TestDelegate("Emit (value type)                ", emitValueTypeGetterDelegate);
    TestDelegate("Emit (reference type)            ", emitReferenceTypeGetterDelegate);

    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void TestDelegate(string description, Func<object, object> getterDelegate)
{
    const long LOOPS_COUNT = 1_000_000_000;
    var obj = new MyClass();

    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();

    for (long i = 0; i < LOOPS_COUNT; i++)
    {
        getterDelegate(obj);
    }

    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine($"{description}: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
}
```

Comment: Your take on it is interesting (I haven't used IL emits myself). However when I call the returned method, it is not faster than the BuildUntypedGetter i posted before. The returned functions both take 43 seconds for 10*1000*1000*1000 calls for reference types, and about 80 seconds for value types. In the end there is still an indirect call.

Comment: According to [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet), the results for the ILGen and Linq versions are more or less identical at `8.4-8.6 ns/op` with an error of `.2 ns`.  I'd stick with what's easiest to understand (Linq).  Depending on what processing OP is doing with on retrieved values, the most performant solution may be to generate specialized code for _that_ instead.

Comment: @MikeStrobel: On my computer, emitted delegate is much faster. I included program used as benchmark and my results. Can you confirm that you tested outside of Visual Studio, since attached debugger makes emitted version slower?

Comment: Nuf Interestingly, your test code looks 90% the same as mine. So I looked at the differences, which was the MyClass in your exampIe. I changed 1 small thing in your code: Your MyClass struct. I changed it to: public class MyClass
        {
            public string S { get; set; }
            public int I { get; set; }
        }. With this change the results were comparible.. on my system the Emit/Reference was slightly faster, and Emit/Value was slower. Interestingly, changing S and I around (so first the int, then the string.. will change the timing slightly.

Comment: @Floris: After changing `MyClass` from `struct` to `class`, I got these results: `26514 ms, 24226 ms, 10114 ms, 4735 ms`, so while emit remained to be nearly 3x faster for value-types, it is now 5x faster for reference-types (only 4x when `MyClass` property definitions changed to `{get; set;}`). I noticed that emit version is not as fast when benchark runs as 64-bit process (`prefer 32-bit` option disabled), but still much faster than lambda version. I also tried on another two computers, with similar results.

Comment: I am not going to argue about the numbers that you get. It is obvious we have other hardware and settings. You said you were using .NET 4.7, while I am using core 2.0. With my settings (64 bit, release, core2.0 with optimizations on a I7-2630 QM) i get the following numbers: 6963 / 4546 / 8999 / 4178.. the results vary a little between runs, but the general pattern stays the same. This once again shows that optimizations on such a low level are very specific to the environment it is run in. It is unfortunate i can't see the generated IL from those lambdas, it might explain a few things...

Comment: I just tested it on another machine to see how things would fare (same binary, but now a faster machine: I7-4790 @3.6Ghz). The results are: 4077/2373/5230/2627, making the emit version slower.@MikeStrobel you are probably correct in that I need to look for optimizations in other places. The explanation on the delegate/covariant was also helpful. Could you make that an answer

Comment: @Floris: So it is `.NET Framework` vs. `.NET Core` that makes those differences between your and my results. With `.NET Core 2.0`, I have `10458 ms, 5528 ms, 11546 ms, 5021 ms`, which is very similar to your results. `.NET Core` has obviously much better optimized lambda compilation so that it produces code that is as effective as emited code.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to just return the getter (get_Id) as a Func without the extra cast and call?

Not in a way that satisfies your requirements.  While it is generally possible to dynamically bind a delegate directly to a method (or property accessor), the delegate type must be signature-compatible with the method you are binding to.  That's not the case for you.

Consider this example:

```
class MyClass {
    string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Here, your accessor expressed in terms of `Func<,>` would be `Func<MyClass, String>`.  You, however, want a `Func<object, object>`.  You're changing both the argument type and the return type.  That is only permissible within certain constraints.

The type `Func<-T, +TReturn>` is **contravariant** on its input type `T` and **covariant** on its output type `TReturn`.  Thus, a `Func<,>` instance is convertible to another instantiation when the target type is **more specific** for `T` or **less specific** for `TReturn`.  For example:

> `Func<object, *>` is convertible to `Func<string, *>` because a function that takes in an `object` can always take in a `string`.  The reverse is not true.
>
> `Func<*, string>` is convertible to `Func<*, object>` because a function that returns a `string` always returns an `object`.  Again, the reverse is not true.

In C#, these rules are strictly enforced.  A generic parameter can be covariant when it only appears as an output; or contravariant when it only appears as an input.  Furthermore, this variance is only applicable to **reference types**, meaning `Func<*, int>` is not assignable to `Func<*, object>`.

I'm afraid there's no way around it: any method you bind to a `Func<object, object>` must accept an `object` argument, which means you need an intermediate method that casts down to your source type.  It also needs to explicitly box primitive return values.  While you could eliminate some of the conversions by emitting the IL directly, as @Ňuf has shown, I don't think you'll see a meaningful impact.

However, depending on how you're using the values you pull out, there may be a better way.  Instead of using generated code to pull values into the C# universe where you can operate on them, it may be feasible to do the opposite: push that logic down into generated code, which you could specialize according to the types you're working with.  Or, alternatively, make that logic generic, and use the runtime code generation to dispatch to the correct generic instantiation.